# Django, override pip installed app in my own app

Tags: django, project-structure

Suppose I pip installed `django-nice` for my project and it is installed in `nice` directory under my virtualenv.

There are times I'd like to override or extend the `django-nice`

I created `nice-custom` in my apps folder and placed the override code there.

I hesitated to use the name `nice` instead in my apps folder assuming there'll be name conflicts.

(Of course one could fork the lib and maintain the fork, but I find it requires more work than this way)

Is there a way to use the name `nice` in my apps folder and have the original `nice` app coexist with mine?

** edit

For instance
`from nice.models import Nice` would result in error, because `nice` can refer to the nice folder in the virtualenv or one under my project directory.

Comment: What is it that you're concerned about exactly? What name conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

Add an alternative path to your app.
You can add the path with a .pth file in your python dist-packages.
An Ubuntu Example:

Assume that your django-nice is at /home/username/my-project/django-nice

```
$ sudo nano /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/my-django-nice.pth
```

The file:

```
/home/username/my-project
```

Then in your code:

```
from my-project.django-nice import nice
```